# How to count the number of occurrences per month?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a program and want to generate reports from it. The program is for a grocery store that does deliveries. A customer places an order and the program captures the various items that the customer wishes to purchase, e.g. Order 21 and the program lists the various items relating to that specific order.

I would like to generate a SQL query that counts the number of orders that customers place each month and want it to look like this

```
No of orders Month
10           Jan
20           Feb
30           March
```

The SQL that I had which is

```
SELECT COUNT(OrderID) AS "Number Of Orders", datepart(month, order_date) AS "Month"
FROM "ORDER"
Group by datepart(month, order_date);
```

Displays

```
Number of Orders  Month
16                9
```

However this is the count of all the orders for the various months and is only displayed in month 9 (September.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Too many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: Some raw data would help too

Comment: have u just tried with `group by(month)`? `datepart()` is giving the number of month not the exact month your **look alike** thing specifies

Comment: Ok so I managed to get it ordered by each month but its only showing the month number, how do i get it to show the month name?

Comment: select month(order_preffered_date) as "Month", COUNT(OrderID) as "Number Of Orders"
from "ORDER"

group by month(order_preffered_date)
order by month(order_preffered_date)
;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
select COUNT(OrderID) as "Number Of Orders",DATENAME(mm,order_date) as "Month" from "ORDER" group by DATENAME(mm,DueDate) order by 2
```